# How do I get elements in a 'column' to right-align?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a simple two column table; I want a way to align the data in the first column to the right and to be able to style the two elements separately. Perhaps a table is not the best solution here, but I don't know what else to try. I tried with column groups, but it isn't working. Even when I try applying `text-align: right` to the 'label' element.

```
<table>
<colgroup>
<col class="label" />
<col class="price" />
</colgroup>
<tr>
<td><label>Subtotal:</label></td>
<td>$135.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Taxes:</label></td>
<td>$11.23</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're probably talking about heading cells, I'd go for a different approach:

```
<style type="text/css">
  table th { text-align: right; }
  table td { text-align: left; }
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Right aligned</th>
    <td>Left aligned</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I never thought of using th element on the side, only along the top. makes a lot of sense, though.. and makes the code cleanest even if it does change what I had a bit.. changes it for the better!

Answer (score 2):

Give id or class to your HTML tags. eg ..
Then use css to style them as you want.

```
tr#cell1{
text-align:right;

}
```

Use this for every row yoou want to align seperately

Answer (score 1):

Label doesn't right align because it is an inline-element. If you give it `display:block` or `display:inline-block` it will fill the whole table cell and apply your right align:

```
label {
 display: block;
 text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: that is a great point. Explains why it wasn't working before.

Answer (score 0):

This should do!

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .one { width:100px; border:1px solid red; }
    .one label { display:block; width:100%; text-align:right; }
    .two { width:150px; border:1px solid green; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <tr>
   <td class="one"><label>one</label></td>
   <td class="two">two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no need to put a div inside the `td` element to align the text. Adding the `text-align` rule to the table division is sufficient

Comment: I've always found styling td's makes older vers of IE angry with me. But, alas. I concede that the div is emblematic of my incurable case of divitis. Cheers, E.

Comment: Removed the div and added a label, per the questioner's, eh, question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the table cell a class

```
<td class="sub">…</td>
```

and then style them with CSS:

```
table td {
  // style for all except .sub
}

table td.sub {
  text-align: right;
  // and other styles that differ from rest
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to turn the `td` element into `th` you can do this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  table td:first-child { text-align: right; }
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Right aligned</td>
    <td>Left aligned</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It works well with Firefox, Chrome and IE 8 (probably IE 7 too).